# configure Amazon s3 bucket to run Lambda function created in another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Is it possible to configure S3 bucket to run a Lambda function created in a different account? Basically what I'm trying to accomplish is that when new items are added to S3 bucket I want to run a lambda function in another account

Comment: See also: [Amazon S3 triggering another a Lambda function in another account](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45450262/174777)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by providing the full Lambda Function ARN to your S3 bucket. For example inside your bucket settings in the AWS Console: [image]

[This article](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html) will help you configure the correct IAM for cross account invocation. Also take a look at the [AWS Lambda Permissions Model](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/intro-permission-model.html). Note that as far as I know the bucket and the Lambda function have to be in the same region!