# Amazon S3 triggering another a Lambda function in another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want to run a lambda in Account B when any object comes into Account A S3 bucket.

But I heard that we can access Lambda from the same account S3 only, for cross-account S3 Lambda access I must run Lambda within same account and make another trigger which runs another account Lambda:

1. S3(Account A)--> Lambda(Account B)- not possible
2. S3(Account A)--> Lambda(Account A)-->Lambda(Account B)- Possible

Can someone help me which option is possible? If so how?

Answer (score 33):

@John's Solution works but there are certain steps I would like to add to his answer.

- The **S3** bucket and the **Lambda** need to be in the same region. For example, both should be created in `us-east-1` region. Different regions would throw an error as below:

> The notification destination service region is not valid for the bucket location constraint

Below is the Steps I followed to create the trigger:

```
Account-A.S3-bucket -> Account-B.Lambda-function
```

1. From Terminal, switch to Account-B's AWS profile where the Lambda would reside
2. Run the below command, change the parameters for your case:

   `aws lambda add-permission \
   --region {Account-B.Lambda region Eg. us-east-1} \
   --function-name {Account-B.Lambda name} \
   --statement-id 1 \
   --principal s3.amazonaws.com \
   --action lambda:InvokeFunction \
   --source-arn arn:aws:s3:::{Account-A.S3 name} \
   --source-account {Account-A.account-id} \
   --profile {Account-B.profile-name}`

You might get statement-id exists error, increment statement-id and re-run command again in this case.

1. Go to `Account-A`'s **S3** bucket and under *Properties*'s tab > under *Events*
2. Select *Add Notification*
3. Add the following fields:

   `Name: ObjectCreation
   Events: ObjectCreate (All)
   Send to: Lambda function
   Lambda: Add Lambda function ARN
   Lambda function ARN:
   your-lambda-arn`

Note: The Lambda function might still show an error but new objects added in the S3 bucket trigger the lambda and print(event) logs appear in Cloudwatch logs.

Answer (score 16):

I managed to **successfully trigger** an AWS Lambda function in Account B from an upload to an Amazon S3 bucket in Account A.

```
Account-A.S3-bucket -> Account-B.Lambda-function
```

Here's what I did:

- Created the **Amazon S3 bucket in Account A**
- Created the **Lambda function in Account B**
- Added a [**Resource-Based Policy** for AWS Lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-resource-based.html#access-control-resource-based-example-s3-invoke-function) to the Lambda function via the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) that allowed the S3 bucket to call `lambda:InvokeFunction` on the Lambda function
- Added a **Bucket Policy** to the S3 bucket to permit `GetObject` access from anywhere (this should be locked-down further, but was sufficient for the experiment)
- Configured an **Event** for `ObjectCreate (All)` on the S3 bucket, referencing the Lambda function via its ARN
- **Uploaded** a file to the Account-A.S3-bucket
- The Account-B.Lambda-function was **successfully triggered**

I then repeated the experiment with the **bucket in a different region and it failed**, saying:

> The notification destination service region is not valid for the bucket location constraint

Comment: I have added getobject policy but still am getting access denied.
this bucket has encryption policy to read object do i have to specify anything for that encryption to pass?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "has encryption policy"? Do you mean the objects are encrypted with SSE-KMS? Also, what are you doing that receives the Access Denied message (is it in the Lambda function)? Feel free to Edit your question to add more details.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you do this in clear steps:

I defined (Customer Account) as the account that contains the S3 resource, "Service Account" as the account that contains the Lambda function, that will access the S3 resource.

1. Create assumed role on Customer Account with full S3 access,
2. Create trust policy in assumed role pointing at Lambda ARN
3. Attach IAM policy to Lambda execution role on Service Account - pointing at Customer account / assumed role
   (Reference: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-assume-iam-role/)
4. Create object notification event on target S3 bucket on customer account, to notify Lambda ARN on service account.
   (Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putBucketNotificationConfiguration-property)

Answer (score 0):

In the new S3 console, go to S3 console and open your bucket. Click on the Properties tab -> Events. You need to give S3 permission to invoke the Lambda function. Refer: [configure Amazon s3 bucket to run Lambda function created in another account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37178718/configure-amazon-s3-bucket-to-run-lambda-function-created-in-another-account)

Comment: Wouldn't you say this question is a duplicate of that question? If so, the thing to do is flag this question as a duplicate and provide the link to the other.  That will put the question in queue for higher rep users to vote om whether to close one question as a duplicate of the other.  If not, please help me understand why not.  It looks like essentially the same question, to me.

Answer (score 0):

Both options should be possible. So you can go with the first option, which is minimalistic.

Use the Cross Account access feature in IAM to grant access to S3(Account A) from Lambda(Account B).

This is achieved by creating a IAM Role in Account B which is granted to acceses to the bucket in Account A and allowed to assume by the Lambda (In Account B).

For further details refer the following documentation from AWS.

- [Using Resource-Based Policies for AWS Lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-resource-based.html) [Example 2: Bucket
- [Owner Granting Cross-Account Bucket Permissions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html)

Comment: {
   "Sid": "InvokeLambda",

   "Action": [
    "lambda:InvokeFunction"
   ],
   "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:AccountB-ID:function_name",
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Principal": {
    "AWS": "AccountB-ID"
   }

  }

Comment: I tried to put above policy for the Account A bucket but it is not allowing me am getting error

Comment: {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::PRODUCTION-ACCOUNT-ID:role/UpdateAPP"
  }
}

and Do i need to have Assume Role policy also attached to my IAM Role in account B??