# For the open data in s3 from AWS, how can I register some notification when new open data landed in its bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to achieve the ask from the title. For example, my architecture design involves trigger a Lambda function whenever a new data land on the open data s3 bucket (say this one: https://registry.opendata.aws/sentinel-2/). 
I read https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html and  [Amazon S3 triggering another a Lambda function in another account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45445572/amazon-s3-triggering-another-a-lambda-function-in-another-account) but I non of those really help me so far. Had anyone done similar task before? Thanks in advance!

Comment: That page you linked has SNS topics that you can subscribe to. If all the buckets you need to be notified about have these, you can just subscribe to those and invoke lambda (NB - lambda must be in same region as SNS topic).

Comment: @KMo Thanks for commenting. I think I should give a another example that without an SNS topic: https://registry.opendata.aws/mogreps/. What would you do in this case?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you want to happen when an object is created in the Amazon S3 bucket? What have you tried so far, and what difficulties have you encountered?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thanks for commenting! So I would like to receive an notification (SNS or other sort of notification) that whenever a new file is landed on a bucket which open to public but without an open SNS topic attach to the bucket, so that I can trigger an downstream lambda function (which is a flask base for example.) Please let me know if my question is still not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure **Amazon S3 events** to send a message to an Amazon SNS Topic *OR* have it trigger an AWS Lambda function.

If you wish to do any further logic (eg checking specific permissions), you would need to do that within the Lambda function.

See: [Configuring Amazon S3 Event Notifications - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html)

Comment: Thanks John! You mean even under the condition that the s3 bucket is an open data source that I don't have control with, and I still able to configure Amazon S3 event?

Comment: No. Amazon S3 events can only be configured by somebody who has the appropriate permissions on the S3 bucket. (Sorry, I didn't realise what you meant by "open data in S3". You should ask the bucket owner if they have (or are willing to setup) such a notification.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks a lot for your help John!