# AWS Glue Spark ETL writing to S3 wont trigger S3 Events

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I have a few Glue Spark ETL jobs that extract and transform data from a RDS instance to a S3 Buckets. No problems here.
In these buckets, I've set up events configured to trigger Lambda functions on `All object create events, All object delete events`, but the ELT does not trigger the events.

```
Something triggers ETL -> ETL reads/transforms data -> ETL Writes to S3 -> S3 Event triggers Lambda

                                                                         /\
                                              Works fine until here.         Event does not happen.
```

All searches I've made point to triggering ETL with S3 events, not the opposite. Why would this not trigger an event, when the interaction with the CLI do ?

Note: the RDS and the ETL jobs are being run in an AWS account different from the account where the buckets are. I don't expect this to impact the events.

Comment: Maybe this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45445572/amazon-s3-triggering-another-a-lambda-function-in-another-account

Comment: Have you enabled event tracking for your bucket in cloud trail. It needs that to be set for the event to actually trigger the lambda

Comment: The event worked before when I was using the CLI to send data to the bucket. I don't think triggering the lambda is the issue.

Comment: @Auyer did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Nick Dima I ended up using a different solution.