# Lambda s3 trigger not seeing bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Have a Lambda function I'm trying to finish setting up.

Lambda function is in account A, Bucket I want to hit is in account B.

Under the, "Below is a summary of the Amazon S3 resources and API calls your function's code has access to..." all the S3 actions I would need are listed with the corresponding

Allow: arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/folder1/*
Allow: arn:aws:s3:::mybucket

When I put S3 on the event trigger and go to the drop-down of the buckets I want to use as the event source, the above buckets are not listed, only those in account A.

Ops guys are stating the access should work, but no matter how I change the roles and/or policies, I cannot set the event sources to see the buckets in account B.  I do not have access to go in and manipulate the S3 bucket I want to hit directly.

Not sure if this is me doing something wrong, or just something we need to tweak on the access level.

Comment: if you do not think this is a duplicate, please explain the different and we can reopen for more answers.

Comment: That answer also links to: [configure Amazon s3 bucket to run Lambda function created in another account](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37178718/174777)

Comment: The post you linked asked if it was possible, which I know it is.  I'm trying to determine where to start trouble-shooting the issue.  My issue is that when I add the S3 trigger, the bucket does not exist in the dropdown even though the Lambda ARN has already been given full access to the bucket I want.

Comment: Buckets in another account will never appear in that list. Instead, did you try putting the ARN of the Lambda function into the S3 console for the Event Notification, as per [configure Amazon s3 bucket to run Lambda function created in another account](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37178718/174777)?

Comment: "Buckets in another account will never appear in that list."  Aha! This is what I needed.  I need the ops guys to take care of then since my access is basically nill to that bucket.  Thanks!